# how to get text from multiple repeated elements?

Tags: jquery

I need to retrieve text information on click event on media div from multiple repeated HTML structure using jquery.

```
<div class="activity-list">
    <div class="media">
        <a class="pull-left" href="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/592781386324549633/5QdIRp9T_normal.png">
            <img class="media-object" src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/592781386324549633/5QdIRp9T_normal.png" alt="">
        </a>
        <div class="media-body">
            <a target="_blank" class="pull-left" href="https://twitter.com/Ford Motor Company">
                <strong>Ford Motor Company  @Ford</strong>
            </a>
            <br>
            <small class="text-muted">06-02-2015 05:53 PM</small>
            <small data-original-title="Favorite" data-toggle="tooltip" class="text-muted favorite"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>0</small>
            <div class="fb_desc">
                "@Barsotta Happy 100,000 miles, Justin! Here's to your next milestone with your truck!"
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media">
        <a class="pull-left" href="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/592781386324549633/5QdIRp9T_normal.png">
            <img class="media-object" src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/592781386324549633/5QdIRp9T_normal.png" alt="">
        </a>
        <div class="media-body">
            <a target="_blank" class="pull-left" href="https://twitter.com/Ford Motor Company">
                <strong>Ford Motor Company  @Ford</strong>
            </a>
            <br>
            <small class="text-muted">06-02-2015 08:37 PM</small>
            <small data-original-title="Favorite" data-toggle="tooltip" class="text-muted favorite"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>22</small>
            <div class="fb_desc">
                "We teamed up with @jonathanadler to create the ultimate road trip u2014 driving directions here: http://t.co/UzE37As167 http://t.co/exDDFJmnGL" </div>
            <div class="ista_usr_img">
                <a data-rel="prettyPhoto" href="http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CGhAyeXUcAEJjA5.jpg">
                    <img alt="" class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CGhAyeXUcAEJjA5.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jquery code to find clicked on media:

```
$('.activity-list.media').click(function (e) {
        alert('media');
  });
```

But did not received any alert message while clicking on media div.

**Question Update:**

All media div is set on activity-list div after ajax calls,so given solution won't work for me.

Thanks
Sameek

Comment: `$('.activity-list .media')` Add a space between as `media` is child of `activity-list`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The click event doesn't exist at that point where the event is defined. i need to  use live or delegate the event.

```
$(document).on('click', '.media', function () {
        alert('media');
    });
```

OR

```
$('body').delegate('.media','click',function(){
     alert('media');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your element selector is wrong please try this:-

```
$('.activity-list .media').click(function (e) {
    alert('media');
 });
```

`.activity-list.media` will select element have both classes `.ctivity-list` and `.media` but `.activity-list .media` this will select element with class .media inside element having class `activity-list`

hope this will helpfull.

Comment: .activity-list.media is a multiple class selector so it picks up element(s) with more than one class on them  i.e. <div class="activity-list media" />

Answer (score 1):

Please see the code below, here how it's done

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".activity-list .media").click(function() {
    alert("media");

  })


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="activity-list">
  <div class="media">
    <a class="pull-left" href="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/592781386324549633/5QdIRp9T_normal.png">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/592781386324549633/5QdIRp9T_normal.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
      <a target="_blank" class="pull-left" href="https://twitter.com/Ford Motor Company">
        <strong>Ford Motor Company  @Ford</strong>
      </a>
      <br>
      <small class="text-muted">06-02-2015 05:53 PM</small>
      <small data-original-title="Favorite" data-toggle="tooltip" class="text-muted favorite"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>0</small>
      <div class="fb_desc">
        "@Barsotta Happy 100,000 miles, Justin! Here's to your next milestone with your truck!"
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="media">
    <a class="pull-left" href="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/592781386324549633/5QdIRp9T_normal.png">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/592781386324549633/5QdIRp9T_normal.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
      <a target="_blank" class="pull-left" href="https://twitter.com/Ford Motor Company">
        <strong>Ford Motor Company  @Ford</strong>
      </a>
      <br>
      <small class="text-muted">06-02-2015 08:37 PM</small>
      <small data-original-title="Favorite" data-toggle="tooltip" class="text-muted favorite"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>22</small>
      <div class="fb_desc">
        "We teamed up with @jonathanadler to create the ultimate road trip u2014 driving directions here: http://t.co/UzE37As167 http://t.co/exDDFJmnGL"</div>
      <div class="ista_usr_img">
        <a data-rel="prettyPhoto" href="http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CGhAyeXUcAEJjA5.jpg">
          <img alt="" class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CGhAyeXUcAEJjA5.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```